# Finding coefficients of linear combination of independent rows in matrix

Tags: java, linear-algebra

Doing project in Java. I use Gauss Jordain algorithm to find which rows and columns of a matrix are linearly independent and which are linear combinations of the independent ones. I can find rank by rows and columns.

But what I really need, and am lost on how to do, is find coefficients that generate dependent rows and columns as linear combination of independent ones.

I guess answer is in some modification of Gauss Jordain and/or tracking all the multiplication and division coefficients, but my brain is locking up on how to do it.

Basic function is reduction to row echelon form and then I build others on it.

```
    public static void toRREF(double[][] M) {
        int rowCount = M.length;
    if (rowCount == 0)          
    return;
    int columnCount = M[0].length;
    int lead = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < rowCount; r++) {
      if (lead >= columnCount)
      break;
        {
         int i = r;
         while (M[i][lead] == 0) {
           i++;
           if (i == rowCount) {
        i = r;
        lead++;
        if (lead == columnCount)
        return;
           }
         }
         double[] temp = M[r];
         M[r] = M[i];
             M[i] = temp;
        }
        {
        double lv = M[r][lead];
        for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
        M[r][j] /= lv;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            if (i != r) {
                double lv = M[i][lead];
                for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
                M[i][j] -= lv * M[r][j];
            }
        }
        lead++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to solve the following system of equations for each linearly dependent column/row:

B * c = R

Where B is the matrix of basis (independent) vectors, and c is the column vector of unknown coefficients of these. R is the current row you are looking at.

So given that you already have a basis via Guass-Jordan, look into methods to solve systems of linear equations, and the coefficient vector you find, c, is the linear equation that combines your basis vectors to give your other, dependent ones.